# pandas: rename axis in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which looks like this:

```
                Column 1
Channel          
Apples            1.0
Oranges           2.0
Puppies           3.0
Ducks             4.0
```

I would like to rename the axis so it looks like this:

```
Channel         Column 1          
Apples            1.0
Oranges           2.0
Puppies           3.0
Ducks             4.0
```

I tried these but got the same error msg:

```
merged_df.rename_axis("Channel")
merged_df.rename_axis("Channel", axis='columns')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Isn't this just a display issue? when your index has a name, in your case `'Channel'` then a row gap is inserted so you can tell the difference between the index and the columns

Comment: That's it, I don't want there to be a row gap. I'm trying to recreate the data in an excel file and it doesnt have a row gap.

Comment: Well I'm not sure you can do that because I can't find an option to change the display option, if you think about it, it behaves this way to help you I don't see what the harm is

Comment: @Boosted_d16 Isn't `reset_index()` pretty close to what you want? It seems gap-less and Excel-friendly.

Comment: Yes but then I have the index ints, id have to manually delete that column. Problem is, I'm trying to replicate something hence I need to do this odd task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a hack to get you what you eventually wanted it to look like.

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s{2,}', index_col='Channel', engine='python')
df
```

[image]

```
df_excel_format = df.rename_axis('Channel', axis=1)
del(df_excel_format.index.name)
df_excel_format
```

[image]

Comment: I still get the "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error.

Comment: It works fine for me in Pandas `0.18.1` and I'm not able to reproduce that error either for the data you've provided.

Comment: Try restarting your kernel and such because I don't see an issue regarding the correctness of my code.