# Pandas Dataframe to HTML remove index

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, flask

I'm using a panda dataframe to read csv data into a Flask project. I'm trying to remove the Dataframe indexes in the HTML table using the set_index method:

```
overviewTable.set_index('Tower Number', inplace=True)
```

When I use this Method the Tower Number Header jumps down a row below all the other headers.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row table-responsive">
   <div class="tower-table">
       {{ overview|safe }}
   </div>
</div>
```

and the Python:

```
overview = pandas.read_csv('../overview_table.csv')
overviewTable = overview[cols]
overviewTable.set_index('Tower Number', inplace=True)

@app.route('/')
def dash():

    return render_template('dash.html', overview=overviewTable[1:167].to_html())
```

And the CSS:

```
.tower-table {
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: darkgrey;
border-color: #003430;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.tower-table tr {
height: 50px;
}
.tower-table thead tr  {
height: 100px;
border-top: none;
}
```

Is there another method to remove the indexes without affecting the headers.
Or is there anything I could do in the CSS etc to stop the header moving down a row

Comment: Instead of setting a column as index, I'd leave it as a column and use `.to_html(index=False)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: rename axis in df](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508001/pandas-rename-axis-in-df)

Comment: Yeah that method worked perfectly. Thanks @ayhan

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As mentioned by @ayhan in the comments you can use `.to_html(index=False)` to surpress the index to be included in the html table.

Just posted it because not everyone might see the comment.

Comment: Also: `index_names=False`

Comment: @EmreSülün what is that?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813123/pandas-dataframe-styler-html-display-without-index), one can now use the "hide_index()" function in Pandas (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Hiding-the-Index-or-Columns) just before calling "render()":

```
def highlight_oddRow(s):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if s.name % 2 else '' for v in s]

table = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [6,7,8,9,10]})

with open ('out.html','w') as out:
    print >> out, table.style.apply(highlight_oddRow,axis=1).hide_index().render()
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in our answer

Comment: Referencing other sources is fine, but you should add an excerpt from said source to your answer showing and explaining the information. Your answer on SO should be complete in itself and offer the link for further reading.

Comment: Ok, I provided some additional code to make the answer self-containing.