# Pandas DataFrame styler HTML display without index?

Tags: pandas, pandas-styles

I have a pandas dataframe, I'm using the `df.style` object to make it highlight odd-numbered rows, so:

```
def highlight_oddRow(s):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if s.name % 2 else '' for v in s]

table = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [3,9,8,0,2], 'b': [5,95, 9, 25,5], 'c': [23,54, 2, 3,5], 'row': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

with open ('out.html','w') as out:
    print >> out, table.style.apply(highlight_oddRow, axis=1).render()
```

However, this always prints out the index. Is there a way to tell it not to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked through the source code for `pandas.formats.style.Styler`, and couldn't find a super-easy way to do it. So instead here is a hacky way. Basically I tell the CSS for the table to not display elements with class `row_heading` and the top left empty box, which has classes `blank level0`.

```
import pandas as pd

def highlight_oddRow(s):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if s.name % 2 else '' for v in s]

table = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [3,9,8,0,2], 'b': [5,95, 9, 25,5], 'c': [23,54, 2, 3,5], 'row': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

with open ('out.html','w') as out:
    # Get the styler for the table
    styler = table.style

    # Set the display to none for row headings, and the blank box in the top left corner for the column headings
    styler.set_table_styles(
        [{'selector': '.row_heading',
          'props': [('display', 'none')]},
         {'selector': '.blank.level0',
          'props': [('display', 'none')]}])

    print >> out, styler.apply(highlight_oddRow, axis=1).render()
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Since this is the first question that popped up when I searched for this issue on Stack Overflow, I thought it would be good to share a recent development: on Nov-17 a [PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/b00e62c273cd60739b538314156b65f0f79350f9) was committed to the pandas repo that added the `hide_index` method to `styler` objects.

You can just call it before render:

```
def highlight_oddRow(s):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if s.name % 2 else '' for v in s]

table = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [3,9,8,0,2], 'b': [5,95, 9, 25,5], 'c': [23,54, 2, 3,5], 'row': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

with open ('out.html','w') as out:
    print >> out, table.style.apply(highlight_oddRow, axis=1).hide_index().render()
```

Keep in mind the docs still claim these features are provisional and subject to change. More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Hiding-the-Index-or-Columns.

Answer (score 13):

This can be done by using the `hide_index()` method such as below

```
print >> out, table.style.hide_index().apply(highlight_odd_row, axis=1).render()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a cheat way of doing this, but you could always set one of the other columns of your dataframe as the index? e.g. DataFrame.set_index('a')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index.html) states that the `hide_index` method has been:

> Deprecated since version 1.4.0: This method should be replaced by [`hide(axis="index", **kwargs)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html)

The code is self-explanatory - it hides the indices. So, an updated solution for this question is:

```py
def highlight_oddRow(s):
    return ['background-color: yellow' if s.name % 2 else '' for v in s]

table = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [3,9,8,0,2],
    'b': [5,95, 9, 25,5],
    'c': [23,54, 2, 3,5],
    'row': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

with open("out.html", "w") as out:
    out.write(table.style
              .apply(highlight_oddRow, axis=1)
              .hide(axis="index")
              .to_html())  # render() also deprecated
```